# Decode JSON-String from POST-request in PHP Zend 2

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I could really need a help.

json_decode returns NULL.

I get the string from the POST:

```
$arrayOfItems = $request->getPost()->get('arrayOfItems');
```

The string looks like this:

```
'[{id: 161, value1: 1, value2: 1},{id: 162, value1: 2, value2: 2},{id: 163, value1: 3, value2: 3}]'
```

And I try to get the ids into an array:

```
$decodedArray = json_decode($arrayOfItems);
$ids = array();
foreach ($decodedArray as $v) {
    $ids[] = $v->id;
}
```

But json_decode returns NULL.

Any help is welcome.

Kind regards
rholtermann

Answer (score 3):

The keys in $arrayOfItems need to be strings for json_decode to work here.  For example, the following would work:

```
'[{"id": 161, "value1": 1, "value2": 1},{"id": 162, "value1": 2, "value2": 2},{"id": 163, "value1": 3, "value2": 3}]'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. json_decode works according to RFC 4627 specification. Link: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4627.html

Answer (score 0):

There might be a couple things here.  Primarily, I'm not sure that's valid JSON.

Second, if `$arrayOfItems` has the quotes around it in it's output, it won't work.

If you have control of the API you're requesting from, check it's output and figure out why it has the single quotes.  If not, you can regex out the single quotes, but depending on your output, you should be careful with this as you might need them.